# RF circuit: How do I calculate the power of signal?

Tags: amplifier, rf, antenna, signal, communication

I have the following schematic of a RF circuit with helical antenna of 5 turns which I'm analysing

[image]

For simplification, I replaced the antenna with an equivalent resistor of 140 Ω as in the below schematic.

[image]

V1 is an AC source square wave generator of frequency 2 MHz and positive amplitude 6 V.

Then, I simulated the transient voltage at node 6 and current through the antenna resistor R4, which looks like as below.

[image]

Now, how should I calculate the power of the signal which the antenna is radiating? Should I do a summation of voltage times current at each time instance and take average over all points i.e. the power dissipated in resistor is the same as the signal power that is being radiated?

$$P(W)=\frac{1}{N} ∑(V_{cc}-V_6 ) I_{R4}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: No, that will give you a overly optimistic estimate of the radiated power, because this assumes that all the power that goes into an antenna is radiated.

Comment: What other factors do I need to consider?